# How to find torrents based on size?

Tags: bittorrent, google-search

I'm looking for a torrent but I only know it's size is above 50GB. I have no other information. I want to just find torrents whose size is bigger than 50GB and check each one.

What are some ways to find it? Are there any search engine that would help me to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might use [this python script](https://github.com/laomayi/simDHT). But The chances to find you torrent are *very* low.